# How to determine if Pressed key is Underscore Or Minus? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-events

The problem is that for both underscore and minus the keyvalue is 189, and the keycode is Keys.OemMinus. So I am unable to check whether pressed key is underscore or minus. Please Help.

```
private void Some_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
       if(Pressed key is minus/dash)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("minus");
       }

       if(pressed key is underscore)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("underscore");
       }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the asp.net tag is relevant, not WinForms? In the latter case, take a look at the `Shift` and/or `Modifiers` property of the `KeyEventArgs` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a WinForms project, use the `KeyPress` event instead of the `KeyDown` event:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyChar == '-')
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Minus");
    }
    if (e.KeyChar == '_')
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Underscore");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the things needs to be done under KeyDown event.

Comment: Why? Please explain why you want to do that in Keydown?

Comment: Its tree list of dev express. I want to move on node according to the pressed key. Now I think this can be done with KeyPress instead of KeyDown as there is KeyChar available there.

Comment: I have tested this with DevExpress 15.2 and it works as expected. Please show your exact code (update the question) and say what error you get (compiler, runtime?)