# How to emulate a keypress of '_' or '=' with System.Windows.Forms Keys?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am emulating keypresses in **Windows 10** with **C#** and `System.Windows.Forms`.

I can emulate lots of characters, but I cannot figure out how to do characters like an **underscore** or **equals** sign which does not appear to be on the [list of keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=net-5.0).

Comment: `Keys.Shift | Keys.D7` for my keyboard. It's not characters, it's actual keyboard keys

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: `Keys.OemMinus`. 11 and 12 I don't have on my keyboard, just `-/_` and `=/+`

Comment: view this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087435/how-to-determine-if-pressed-key-is-underscore-or-minus-c-sharp

Comment: Speaking of emulation, are you looking for `SendKeys.SendWait("_");` and `SendKeys.SendWait("=");`?